# C# - Creating reports

Tags: c#, reporting

Iam trying to create some reports in C# using report.rdlc. I want to create reports based on store procedures. I want to show the data that store procedures return in textboxes. For example textbox1 contains values from store procedure 1 and textbox2 contains values from store procedure 2 and so on.

Is it possible to that?

Comment: Can you be more vague?  Including information like what you've tried, the RDBMS type you're trying to pull from would make it entirely too easy to help.

Comment: I have a table in a database with full of products, I want to create reports about the procuts. In the report I want information like how meny products I have in the table, how meny products are in each category. Then I want to create some charts as well. I havent done enything right know and was looking for some advise to accomplish this. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

"Is it possible to that?" -- Yes, everything you've mentioned is possible.

You'll need to check out a tutorial or something. You could start by taking a look at the FAQ on... http://www.gotreportviewer.com/

but I'm sure there are hundreds of tutorials out there. One approach could be:

1. create the stored procedure(s) to get your data from the DB.
2. create a dataset.
3. create a tableAdapter for each sproc you've created ( the tableAdapters will use the sprocs you created ).
4. create the report itself.
5. create a page with a reportViewer control.
6. during page_load you'll need to have instances of the tableAdapters and call their GetData() functions.
7. You'll then need to add the data datasources to the reportViewer control and call ReportViewer.Refresh().

This isn't a *complete* list of steps but hopefully it gets you going in the right direction. Best of Luck!